# botframework - How to include Adaptive card inside the carousel

Tags: carousel, bots, botframework

Did anybody tried to include adaptivecards inside a carousel? 
I am using nodejs sdk of botframework.

Comment: AdaptiveCard is one type of Card, Thumbnail Card another. Please clarify what you are trying to do and add some code to show what you have done so far, thanks

Comment: I was trying Adaptive card inside the carousel

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is included in [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-CarouselCards) inside the [botbuild-samples repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples).

in this example this is how the cards are built:

```
function getCardsAttachments(session) {
    return [
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title('Azure Storage')
            .subtitle('Offload the heavy lifting of data center management')
            .text('Store and help protect your data. Get durable, highly available data storage across the globe and pay only for what you use.')
            .images([
                builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/data-storage-options/_static/image5.png')
            ])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/', 'Learn More')
            ]),

        new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
            .title('DocumentDB')
            .subtitle('Blazing fast, planet-scale NoSQL')
            .text('NoSQL service for highly available, globally distributed apps—take full advantage of SQL and JavaScript over document and key-value data without the hassles of on-premises or virtual machine-based cloud database options.')
            .images([
                builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/media/documentdb-introduction/json-database-resources1.png')
            ])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/', 'Learn More')
            ]),

        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title('Azure Functions')
            .subtitle('Process events with a serverless code architecture')
            .text('An event-based serverless compute experience to accelerate your development. It can scale based on demand and you pay only for the resources you consume.')
            .images([
                builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/09/fsharp-functions2.png')
            ])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/', 'Learn More')
            ]),

        new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
            .title('Cognitive Services')
            .subtitle('Build powerful intelligence into your applications to enable natural and contextual interactions')
            .text('Enable natural and contextual interaction with tools that augment users\' experiences using the power of machine-based intelligence. Tap into an ever-growing collection of powerful artificial intelligence algorithms for vision, speech, language, and knowledge.')
            .images([
                builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/03/Azure-Cognitive-Services-e1489079006258.png')
            ])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/', 'Learn More')
            ])
    ];
}
```

And this is how they ae sent as a carousel:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    var cards = getCardsAttachments();

    // create reply with Carousel AttachmentLayout
    var reply = new builder.Message(session)
        .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
        .attachments(cards);

    session.send(reply);
});
```