# Carousel in ms bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

Dear Community,
                I have been assigned to work on developing a chat bot for booking flights in ms bot frame work.I am stuck in creating carousel to display the flight result. MS documentation is a bit confusing.I need to display my flight results in waterfall model.Please guide me in creating a carousel/slider in ms bot (C#).

Comment: Have a look at this http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/12/Using-Images-Cards-Carousels-and-Buttons-In-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a similar question that might help: [botframework - How to include Adaptive card inside the carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004675/botframework-how-to-include-adaptive-card-inside-the-carousel)

Basically, you need to create a "card", which is like a small mini form with it's own markup language. That Card would display an individual flight. Then, you insert that card and all the other flight Cards into another, higher up card, which is the Carousel card. The example above linked to the [following repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) and you'll find examples in node as well as C# there. Sample 6 & 7 in particular look like they might help.

That's pretty rough guidance, I know, but your question is quite broad right now. Perhaps tell us specifically where you are with this so far, and what exactly you're stuck with?

Comment: great, glad to help! Please go ahead and "mark as answer" in this case, and let us know if there's more we can help with here on the forums. Good luck with your bot!